# c programming gcc error : assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following function

```
TreeNode* findParentNode(TreeNode *tn, int parentData, int branchSelect)
{
    ListNode *temp1, *temp2;

    if (tn->data == parentData)
    {
        if ((branchSelect == 0 && tn->left == NULL) || (branchSelect == 1 && tn->right == NULL))
            return tn;
    }
    if (tn->left == NULL && tn->right == NULL)
        return NULL;



    temp1 = findParentNode(tn->left, parentData, branchSelect);
    if (temp1 != NULL)
        return temp1;

    temp2 = findParentNode(tn->right, parentData, branchSelect);
    if (temp2 != NULL)
        return temp2;
}
```

The function should return the parent node.
it works well at vs but when I'm running it at gcc I'm getting the error above and I need it to work under gcc as well,
I read about this error but still I didn't find a way to fix it.

Can some1 help me fix it so I can run it at gcc as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always compile with maximum 'nastiness' -Wall under gcc for example

Comment: @KevinDTimm: `Wall` is far from "maximum nastiness". Recommended are at least `-Wextra -Wconversion`, too (which still does not mean "maximum nastiness", though). For strict compliant code, `-Wpedantic` is also a good pick.

Comment: @Olaf - OK, `maximal nastiness`. my point being that -Wall would have found the assignment without cast error

Comment: @KevinDTimm: not sure what you mean. The error above is not even from the warnings, yet it was reported. What else would `-Wall` found here? (btw: we can't know without a [mcve])

Comment: would have found "may not return a value"

Comment: Just one more FYI - this code won't pass any compiler. You call findParentNode inside of findParentNode with incompatible types (sending tn->right and tn-left in the first position where a TreeNode is expected).  It is a prime example of why SO requires a [mcve] and not this cobbled together drivel.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make

```
    ListNode *temp1, *temp2;
```

into

```
    TreeNode *temp1, *temp2;
```

I don't see what's the definition of either one...

Comment: You're right I had a ListNode struct as well to make something else and canceled

Comment: That's more of a comment, than an answer.

Comment: @Olaf, how would you improve this answer?